# How to parse mulitple Json Arrays with the same name in Python

Tags: python, json

I want to parse a Json File where all Json Arrays have the same Name just as the following:

```json
[
    {
        "envelope": {
            "source":"user1",
            "data":{
                "message": "Hello World 0"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "envelope": {
            "source":"user1",
            "data":{
                "message": "Hello World 1"
            }
        }
    }, 
    ...
]
```

And this is my code so far:

```py
def check_messages():
    data = requests.get(urlWhereIGetJson)
    for d in data:
        message = d['envelope']['data']['message']
        print(message)
```

My code is only giving me back the first entry. ("Hello World 0") but I need every message.

I hope somebody can teach me and show how to parse the json correctly.
I am not able to edit the JSON File.

I'm sorry for my english

Comment: I'm getting `Hello World 0 Hello World 1` with your code.

Comment: You need to convert your requests response to json: `data = requests.get(urlWhereIGetJson).json()`

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need

```
response = requests.get(urlWhereIGetJson)
if response.status_code == 200:
    data = json.loads(response.text)
    for record in data:
        print(record['envelope']['data']['message'])
```

For more information https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_requests_response.asp

Answer (score 0):

Saeed already covered how to do this, but if you would like it in a nice Pandas DataFrame, you could do something like this:

```
data = json.load('file.json')
series = pd.Series(data) # Since it's an array, I'll turn that into a Series first
df = pd.json_normalize(series)
```

That DataFrame would automatically unnest inner json objects and represent them with column names like `envelope.source` and `envelope.data.message`.

Edit: Also if you did want this to read the json from requests, just use `json.loads(data.json())`